# Find the area of the triangular region MBN

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

In the figure shown, calculate the area of the triangular region MBN , if a=1u and b=2u.(S:$\frac{2}{5}u^2$)

[image]

(figure out of scale)

I didn't get much, does anyone have an idea for a solution?

Follow the relations I found

$B, M$ and $N$ are points of tangent

Let $O$ is the center of the minor circumference

$AB = BO + OA = AN = AM + MN$

$BO = a = u$

$OA + u = AM + 2u$

$MN = 2u$

$\triangle OAP:OP^2=R^2+r^2$

$\triangle OPH: 
HP^2=R^2+r^2+(R-r)^2 \implies HP=MN=\sqrt{2Rr}$

$MN = \sqrt{2.2u.u}=\sqrt{4u^2} = 2u$

$AB = AN$

$S\triangle BMN=\frac{MN.h}{2} = \frac{2u.h}{2} =\frac{u.h}{2}$

[image]

Comment: Are you sure of the data? Circle centres $O_A$, $O_C$ lie on a parabola with focus $B$ and directrix $AC$: the only way you can have $BO_C=2BO_A$ and $\angle ABC=90°$ is when $BO_C \parallel AC$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca  The question is faithfully transcribed

Comment: I believe you, but that only means some data is wrong.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca  But triangle ABC in the figure is right

Comment: Why is $MN = 2u$?

Comment: But that figure is not to scale: just construct the right figure with GeoGebra (that's easy if you start with a parabola, as I explained above) and you'll see.

Comment: Here's an example of the construction: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3i0T.png

Comment: @Intelligentipauca  There really must be some problem with the figure of the statement. Thanks

Comment: @CalvinLin  I demonstrated how to get to MN=2u in the second drawing